# Blended use of DoH and LoG for blob detection, is there any paper I can cite for this?

Tags: image-processing, image-analysis

**tl;dr:** For blob detection, I determine locally maximal DoH responses in image regions which correspond to negative LoG responses. Is there publication I can cite for such blended use?

---

Two of the most prominent approaches to blob detection in image processing are Laplacian of Gaussians (LoG) and Determinant of Hessians (DoH). Both are based on analysis of local second-order image statistics. One could say, they consider a second-order Taylor expansion of the image intensities $g\left(x\right)$. Lets say, the Matrix $H_x = \nabla^2 g\left(x\right)$ is the corresponding Hessian matrix for an image point $x$. Then, LoG corresponds to
$$
\Delta g\left(x\right) = \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_2^2} = \operatorname{tr} H_x
$$
where $\operatorname{tr} H_x$ is the trace of the Hessian (computed using Gaussian derivative operators). So obviously, LoG corresponds to *the sum of the eigenvalues* of the Hessian.

For DoH, lets also use Gaussian derivative operators for the computation of the Hessian. The determinant of a matrix corresponds to *the product* of its eigenvalues. Thus, the only difference of LoG and DoH is that LoG considers the sum of the eigenvalues, whereas DoH considers the product.

Lets say the two eigenvalues are $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, ordered such that $\left|\lambda_1\right| > \left|\lambda_2\right|$. Using LoG to detect bright blobs, we seek local maxima of $-\lambda_1 -\lambda_2$. This is prone to saddle points, which occur when $\left|\lambda_1\right| \gg \left|\lambda_2\right|$ and $\lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2 < 0$. DoH on the other hand aims to determine local maxima of $\lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2$ and is thus not prone to saddle points. The disadvantage of DoH is that, it is impossible to tell whether a high response of $\lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2$ corresponds to a pair of positive (dark blob) or a pair of negative eigenvalues (bright blob).

So it is quite obvious to combine the best of the two: First, use LoG to determine the set of image points $M = \left\{x : \operatorname{tr} H_x < 0 \right\}$ which *cannot* correspond to *dark* blobs. Second, use DoH to determine the blobs from the remaining image pixels, i.e. determine the local maxima of $\operatorname{det} H_x$ subject to the constraint that $x \in M$.

I expect this is more robust than discarding false-positive DoH detections in post-processing, since the false-positive DoH detections might prevent true-positive detections due to non-maximum suppression.

**Question:** Does this blended use of LoG and DoH have a name? Is there any publication I could cite when using it?

Comment: I think I saw such things in practice. I don't remember any specific paper. Since you formally wrote it, why not do it on yourself?